# Multifunction RegEx for parsing JCL variables - out of working solutions

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm a bit lost creating a RegEx under C#.NET.
I'm doing something like parser, so I use Regex.Replace to search text for certain "variables" and replace them with their "values".
Each variable starts with ampersand ("&") and ends with ampersand (begining of another variable) or dot.
Each variable (as well as text surrounding variables) can only consist of alphanumerical characters and certain "special" characters, that being "$", "@", "#" and "-".
Nor variables, nor the rest of the text could contain space characters (" ").

Now, the problem is that I'm trying to figure out a RegEx replacing one possible ending character ("."), *while not replacing* the other possible ending character ("&").
Which happanes to be quite an issue:

- **"&"+variable+"[^A-Za-z0-9#@$]"** does what I want, except for it also replaces "&" - not acceptable.
- **"&"+variable+"(.)?\b"** replaces dot, but *only if* followed by literal character - not if it's followed by \&\@#\$\- and that *could* occur, so this doesn't work either.
- **"&"+variable+"(.)?(?!A-Za-z0-9)"** does exactly what i want as for the ending characters, except it doesn't recognize true end of variable - this way, search-and-replace for *"&DEN"* also replaces that part in another variable, called *"&DENV"* - of which "&DEN" is a substring. This would create false/misleading results - totally unacceptable.

These were all the possibilities I could think of (and search of); is it possible to do the task I require with one RegEx at all? Under C#.NET RegEx parser?

Just to illustrate desired function:

```
string variable="DEN";
string replaceWith="28";
string replText;
string regex = "<desired regex>";
replText = Regex.Replace(replText, "&"+variable+regex, replaceWith);

replText="&DEN";
```

=> replaced => repltext=="28"

```
replText="&DENV"
```

=> not replaced => repltext=="&DENV"

```
replText="&DEN&DEN"
```

=> replaced => repltext=="2828"

```
replText="&DEN&DENV"
```

=> replaced, not replaced => repltext=="28&DENV"

```
replText="&DEN.anything"
```

=> replaced and dot removed => repltext=="28anything"

```
replText="&DEN..anything"
```

=> replaced and first dot removed => repltext=="28.anything"

variable could also be like "#DE@N-$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works correctly on all of your examples.  I assumed that a variable `&FOO` should only be replaced if it's followed by `.`, `&`, or end-of-string `$`.  If it's followed by anything else, it's not replaced.

In order to match but not capture a terminating `&`, I used a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=&)`.  Assertions force the string to match the regex, but they don't consume any characters, so those characters aren't replaced.  Trailing `.` are still captured and replaced as part of the variable, however.

Finally, a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) is specified to use the captured pattern to do a lookup in the `replacements` dictionary for the replacement value.  If the pattern (variable name) is not found, the text is effectively untouched (the full original capture is returned).

```
class Program
{
    static string ReplaceVariables(Dictionary<string, string> replacements, string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, @"&([\w\d$@#-]+)(\.|(?=&)|$)", m =>
        {
            string replacement = null;
            return replacements.TryGetValue(m.Groups[1].Value, out replacement)
                 ? replacement
                 : m.Groups[0].Value;
        });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] tests = new[]
        {
            "&DEN", "&DENV", "&DEN&DEN",
            "&DEN&DENV", "&DEN.anything",
            "&DEN..anything", "&DEN Foo",
            "&DEN&FOO&DEN"
        };

        var replace = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "DEN", "28" },
            { "FOO", "42" }
        };

        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", test, ReplaceVariables(replace, test));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Ok, I think I finally found it, using ORs. Regex

**(.)?([^A-Za-z0-9#\@\$\&\,\;\:-\<>()\ ]|(?=\&)|\b)**

seems to work fine. I'm just posting this if anyone found it helpfull.*

EDIT: sorry, I haven't refreshed the page and thus reacted without knowing there is a better answer provided by Chris Schmich

Comment: @Chris Schmich - thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of the MatchEvaluator before. It's much more elegand your way - and I suppose even faster, due to lack of need for combining strings _("&"+variable+regex)_ ?

Comment: regex performance is tough to analyze, but yes, I would guess that doing a single scan and collecting the matches and using a `MatchEvaluator` would be faster than running multiple similar regexes.